# How can I drag from a connected vertical list to the first item of a another list below with jQueryUI Sortable?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I have have several ULs vertically down a page. They are setup using jQueryUI's sortable(). My live example is:

http://jsfiddle.net/GVqPF/2/

I can drag from answers to make it the final element in questions. But when I drag from questions to answers the placeholder jumps to the second item in the questions list. At that point I can then drag it to the top. But i can't drag directly to the first position in the Answers list.

[Here is a video](http://screencastle.com/watch/a9114c829c67dd8646efdeb274263f9c) that demonstrates the problem.

Any ideas why I am having this issue dragging from a list above to the first element of a list below?

I've tried editing the padding and margin on both the lists and the sortable items.

Thanks,
Denis

Comment: Could this possibly a browser issue? I can drag everything from Question to Answer and Answer to Question without any problem in Chrome. BTW--the align in IE7 is off.

Comment: I've emulated the issue in FF, Opera and Chrome. Can you drag a Question to the top of the Answers list with out having the placeholder move to the second position first?

Comment: I can't reproduce that issue in Chrome 9, for what it's worth. Questions appear exactly where I drag them within Answers, including the top.

Comment: I've test in the stable chrome channel (v8 atm) on OSx and Win7 and can't get a question to the first position in Answers without dragging the placeholder to the second first.

Comment: Works fine for me in Firefox 3.6.13, Chrome 8.0.552.224 and Opera 11.00 beta build 1111 (all on Windows XP).

Comment: I have the same problem.  When I drag from question down to answers it is impossible to drop it at the top of the answers list.  It always moves to the second position.  At that point, I can then drag it back up to the top of the list.

Comment: works fine for me on chrome on snow leopard

Comment: It always happens to second.You cant get it because when you are moving down to up  it happens like what  jjross said.Instead of that do like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/GVqPF/6/)

Comment: looks like you have to learn the art of dragging :) works for me at chrome, ff and ie8(some alignment issues)

Comment: I've added a video to demonstrate the problem to make sure everyone's on the same page. It's also using a version of the fiddle that freezes the height of the `ul`s, so demonstrate the issue occurs even if the elements don't "jump."

Answer (score 2):

This is my observation and plausible explanation for this weird behavior.

When moving an element from questions container to answers container, the placeholder initially adds itself to the **end of the answers container** before further cursor movement gets it between answer1 and answer2.Ideally, this should not happen as the placeholder should jump before answer1 and then between answer1 and answer2.
***PS:***This effect may not be visible in the jsfiddle window but if you construct a fresh HTML page with the given code, you will see what I am saying.

Further investigation reveals that there is a bug in the sortable jquery UI plugin.
Take the developers version of jquery.ui.sortable.js and find this phrase "var dist = 10000; var itemWithLeastDistance = null".
The objective of this piece of code is to find out the **nearest element** when the cursor traverses from one container to another.

Observe the variable "**cur**" (I have added console.log() commands for firebug). The value of this variable is always **0** . Since the value of cur is always '0', the code thinks wrongly calculates that last <li> element as the '**itemWithLeastDistance**' and wrongly jumps there.

```
//When entering a new container, we will find the item with the least distance and append our item near it 
                var dist = 10000; var itemWithLeastDistance = null; var base = this.positionAbs[this.containers[innermostIndex].floating ? 'left' : 'top'];
                for (var j = this.items.length - 1; j >= 0; j--) {
                    if (!$.ui.contains(this.containers[innermostIndex].element[0], this.items[j].item[0])) continue;
                    var cur = this.items[j][this.containers[innermostIndex].floating ? 'left' : 'top'];
                    //my comments
                    console.log("cur : %s for iteration: %s has base %s", cur, j, base);
                    if (Math.abs(cur - base) < dist) {
                        dist = Math.abs(cur - base); itemWithLeastDistance = this.items[j];
                        //my comments
                        console.debug(this.items[j]);
                    }
                }
```

Let me know what the community thinks. we can report this to jquery ui team.

Answer (score 0):

When you drag an LI from one list to a connected list, the "empty space" in the old list disappears. This causes the lists below it to "move up" on the page, just as your cursor reaches the next list. This causes your dragged item to be hovering over the 2nd space instead of the 1st, forcing you to nudge your cursor up again to get the 1st space.

If your lists are next to each horizontally, you won't see this issue (but, of course, that doesn't help you).

I haven't come up with an actual solution yet, but hopefully this will help frame the problem.

Comment: If this is the case, I'm curious why http://jsfiddle.net/GVqPF/8/ doesn't work as expected.

Comment: Well, your jsfiddle shows pretty clearly my theory is wrong. Interestingly, with your version, I only get the problem the first time I drag an item onto the list. Without even letting go (i.e., never dropping the item), if I drag it back up top and then back down again, it still works. (In Chrome 10).

Comment: Yeah, it's quite odd. The behavior is also the same when you go from the bottom list to the top list--instead of the outline appearing at the end of the top list, it appears at the second-to-end. But, this appears to only happen sometimes. I'm quite baffled.